# Post object inside another object to mongoDB via Spring rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-mongodb

I'm creating a basic crud application for members in a library. I've created a spring api to get the values and insert it into the DB. So when I check it using postman a error is shown. (500: Internal server error)
Below diagram shows a request i tried to sent.

[image]

As shown above I'm sending another object inside the **Member** object and once I removed the **latestBook**, there is no error the value is posted.

I want to resolve this issue, please help me with this.

**API**

```
@PostMapping("/m")
public Member save(@RequestBody Member member){
    repository.save(member);
    return member;
}
```

**Member.java**

```
@Document(collection = "Members")
public class Member {

@Id
private String id;
private String name;
private Book latestBook;
private String gender;
private int contact;

public Member() {
}

public Member(String id, String name, Book latestBook, String gender, int contact) {
    this.id= id;
    this.name = name;
    this.startMembershipDate = startMembershipDate;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.contactNum = contactNum;
}

 //getters , setters and toString method

}
```

**Book.java**

```
public class Book{

private String name;
private String author;
private int year;

public Book(String name, String author, int year) {
    this.name= name;
    this.author= author;
    this.year = year;
}
    //getters , setters and toString method
}
```

I think the problem is with the Book class so please help me to solve this issue.
Not only for posting it does not work for delete either.

Comment: Can you post the error trace to see where the issue is ? AFAIK, you need to use DBRef annotation for link the One-to-One mapping. Please follow https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.

```
@Document(collection = "Members")
public class Member {

@Id
private String id;
private String name;
private Book latestBook = new Book();
private String gender;
private int contact;

public Member() {
}

public Member(String id, String name, Book latestBook, String gender, int contact) {
    this.id= id;
    this.name = name;
    this.startMembershipDate = startMembershipDate;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.contactNum = contactNum;
}

 //getters , setters and toString method

}
```

////////////////////////

```
public class Book{

private String name;
private String author;
private int year;

Book(){}

public Book(String name, String author, int year) {
    this.name= name;
    this.author= author;
    this.year = year;
}
    //getters , setters and toString method
}
```